# Using Azure Search index to index blobs in Azure Blob Storage (Images and Videos)

Tags: asp.net, azure, video, azure-cognitive-search, azure-blob-storage

I want to index blob of type image and video.
From what I have read Azure Search cannot index image and video types.

What I have done is that I was thinking of using the blob's metadata_storage_path. However that is my key and it is encoded.

Decoding it is really a performance killer.

Is there any way I can index images and videos, using azure search index?

If not, is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to index the metadata attached to the blob but not its content, correct? If so, set `dataToExtract` parameter to `storageMetadata` as described in [Controlling which parts of the blob are indexed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-indexing-azure-blob-storage#controlling-which-parts-of-the-blob-are-indexed).

The cost of base64-decoding the encoded `metadata_storage_path` to correlate with the rest of your system is likely to be negligible compared to other work your app is doing, such as calls to the database or Azure Search. However, you can avoid the need for decoding if you fork `metadata_storage_path` into a new non-key field in your index, which won't need to be encoded. You can use [field mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings) to fork the field.

Comment: I want to access the blob that are of type image and video. The only way I can do that is through the metadata_storage_path, that is the key of my index. However it is encodeBase64. In order to get the actual metadata_Storage_path (URL) I need to loop through all the result and use TokenDecodeUrl(), to decode the encoded metatada_storage_path.

OH, can use the metadata_storage_path for the key of my index and as well for another field? That should work. What do you think?

Comment: Once again, you can "fork" the value of metadata_storage_path field into two separate fields in your search index, one encoded (so it can be used as a key) and one un-encoded (so you don't have to decode anything if you don't want to). Please read the [field mappings documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings) that shows how you can do it.